# How to rotate as copied in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

the following code draws three diamonds with their ends fixed at (0,0). Can someone pls suggest a better way to do the same thing, such as drawing one diamond and rotate them as copied? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{picture}(215,20)(0,0)
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{90}{0}}; 
\filldraw[scale=1,color=black](0,0) circle(7cm); % plate
\filldraw[scale=1,white] (0,0)--++(120:2.966)--++(60:2.966)--++(300:2.966)--++(240:2.966) ;
\filldraw[scale=1,white] (0,0)--++(180:2.966)--++(240:2.966)--++(0:2.966)--++(60:2.966) ;
\filldraw[scale=1,white] (0,0)--++(0:2.966)--++(300:2.966)--++(180:2.966)--++(120:2.966) ;

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{picture}  
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the `rotate` option.

Comment: Hi thanks, but the rotate option does not rotate "as copied". SO I am confused how to use it to serve my purpose.

Answer (score 5):

If you are simply trying to reduce keystrokes and avoid manual angle calculation, the easiest way is probably to use a `foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{picture}(215,20)(0,0)
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{90}{0}}; 
\filldraw[scale=1,color=black](0,0) circle(7cm); % plate

\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}
  \filldraw[scale=1,white,rotate=\angle] (0,0)--++(120:2.966)--++(60:2.966)--++(300:2.966)--++(240:2.966) ;

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{picture}  
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned use the rotate option.
You can't really copy TikZ stuff. It is simpler to store the coordinates
in a macro:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\mydiamond{--++(120:2.966)--++(60:2.966)--++(300:2.966)--++(240:2.966)}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{90}{0}}; 
\filldraw[scale=1,color=black](0,0) circle(7cm); % plate
\filldraw[scale=1,white] (0,0) \mydiamond ;
\filldraw[scale=1,white,rotate=120] (0,0) \mydiamond ;
\filldraw[scale=1,white,rotate=240] (0,0) \mydiamond ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The first coordinate `(0,0)` is not part of the macro to allow its reuse somewhere else.
BTW: The `picture` environment is not required

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to remove some useless things. I remove the picture environment
and \pgftransformshift and scale =1. The color black is by default.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw (0,0) circle(7cm);
\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}
  \filldraw[color=white,rotate=\angle] (0,0)--++(120:3)--++(60:3)--++(300:3)--++(240:3);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{picture}(215,20)(0,0)
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%0
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{100}{0}}; 
\filldraw[scale=0.2,color=black](0,0) circle(7cm); 
\path[coordinate, scale=0.2] (-4.15,-2.5)  coordinate(A)++( 60:8.5cm) coordinate(B)++(-60:8.5cm) coordinate(C);
\draw[fill=white] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
%%%%1
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{90}{0}}; 
\filldraw[scale=0.2,color=black](0,0) circle(7cm); 
\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}
  \filldraw[scale=0.2,white,rotate=\angle] (0,0)--++(120:2.966)--++(60:2.966)--++(300:2.966)--++(240:2.966) ;
%%%2
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{90}{0}}; 
\filldraw[scale=0.2,color=black](0,0) circle(7cm);
\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}
\filldraw[scale=0.2,white,rotate=\angle] (0,0)--++(120:1.121)--++(60:1.121)--++(180:1.121)--++(120:1.121)--++(60:1.121)--++(0:1.121)--++(120:1.121)--++(60:1.121)--++(300:1.121)--++(240:1.121)--++(0:1.121)--++(300:1.121)--++(240:1.121)--++(180:1.121)--++(300:1.121)--++(240:1.121) ;
%%%3
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{90}{0}}; 
\filldraw[scale=0.2,color=black](0,0) circle(7cm);
\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}
  \filldraw[scale=0.2,white,rotate=\angle] (0,0)--++(120:00.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(180:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(0:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(180:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(240:0.4)--++(180:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(180:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(0:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(0:0.4)--++(300:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(0:0.4)--++(120:00.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(180:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(0:0.4)--++(120:0.4)--++(60:0.4)--++(300:00.4)--++(240:00.4)--++(0:00.4)--++(300:00.4)--++(240:00.4)--++(180:00.4)--++(300:00.4)--++(240:00.4)--++(0:00.4)--++(300:00.4)--++(60:00.4)--++(0:00.4)--++(300:00.4)--++(240:00.4)--++(0:00.4)--++(300:00.4)--++(240:00.4)--++(180:00.4)--++(300:00.4)--++(240:00.4)--++(180:00.4)--++(120:00.4)--++(240:00.4)--++(180:00.4)--++(300:0.4)--++(240:0.4)--++(0:0.4)--++(300:0.4)--++(240:0.4)--++(180:0.4)--++(300:0.4)--++(240:0.4) ;
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{picture}  
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There must be a better way to do that using recursion...

Comment: I would really like to know that for sure..

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0:0) circle (7cm);
    \foreach \r in {90,210,330}
      \node[fill=white,shape=diamond,aspect=1.725,scale=9,rotate=\r] (a) at (\r:2.85) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes you can do that but it's not very easy to explain why : aspect =1.725, scale =9 and 2.85. You need to make some extra calculations .

Comment: If I'd have the time, I'd built in a scaling mechanism. So I only provided a simple frame and admitted of improvement. Some arithmatics should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks guys, every bit of suggestion was helpful! Anyway, I am sharing (as answer) what I intended to do.

Answer (score 2):

I give a scalable solution. I hope it is ok!!

```
Here is the code:

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radius{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RATIO}{2.966/7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\edge}{\radius*\RATIO}


\filldraw(0,0) circle(\radius cm); % plate

\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}{
\filldraw[white,rotate=\angle] (0,0)--++(60:\edge)--++(120:\edge)--++(-120:\edge)--cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Some other solutions are scalable !