# TikZ: \pgfmathresult problem inside (<angle>:\pgfmathresult) coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

After reading [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9968/how-to-rotate-as-copied-in-tikz), I was playing around to make a command to create a TikZ command with two inputs like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\centering

\newcommand{\mitsubishi}[2]{
% #1 = radius
% #2 = position x,y
\pgfmathparse{2.966/7}
\pgfmathparse{#1*\pgfmathresult}

\filldraw (#2) circle(#1 cm); % plate

\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}{
\filldraw[white,rotate=\angle] (#2)--++(60:\pgfmathresult)--++(120:\pgfmathresult)--++(-120:\pgfmathresult)--cycle;
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\mitsubishi{2}{0,0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I have problems with the command `\pgfmathresult` inside the `\filldraw` command.

Why?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit. Moreover, note that you don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem if I put a different center point, let say (1,1), because the rotation is not done around that point but around (0,0) so i suggest this ultimate solution:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mitsubishi}[2]{
% #1 = radius
% #2 = position x,y
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mymathresult}{#1*2.966/7}   

\filldraw (#2) circle(#1 cm); 
\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}{
\filldraw[white] (#2)--++(60+\angle:\mymathresult)
                     --++(120+\angle:\mymathresult)
                     --++(240+\angle:\mymathresult)
                     --cycle;
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=.5cm](0,0)grid(4,4);
\draw[<->] (5,0)--(0,0)--(0,5);

\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4}{
         \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4}{
         \mitsubishi{.25}{\x,\y}
         }
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to all for let me achiving this result!!!

Bye

Comment: Azoun: Could you please accept one of these answers, so that this post is removed from the "unanswered question" section. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The `\pgfmathresult` is overwritten by the drawing commands.
You have to save it away:

```
\pgfmathparse{2.966/7}
\let\myresult\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{#1*\myresult}
\let\myresult\pgfmathresult

\filldraw (#2) circle(#1 cm); % plate

\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}{
\filldraw[white,rotate=\angle] (#2)--++(60:\myresult)--++(120:\myresult)--++(-120:\myresult)--cycle;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also use `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mitsubishi}[2]{
% #1 = radius
% #2 = position x,y
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mymathresult}{#1*2.966/7}   

\filldraw (#2) circle(#1 cm); 
\foreach \angle in {0,120,240}{
\filldraw[white,rotate=\angle] (#2)--++(60:\mymathresult)--++(120:\mymathresult)--++(-120:\mymathresult)--cycle;
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\mitsubishi{4}{0,0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ops i made a mistake, see the following answer...

Comment: I fixed the indentation in your code. OK?

Comment: @Hendrik OK !. I don't know exactly the rules for the indentation, perhaps there is something special and important to read about "how write answer with TeX code".

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).