# Is there a reason \pgfmathresult doesn't work as a yshift value?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here's something mystifying: I've been trying to use a for loop to create several copies of essentially the same picture stacked vertically on top of one another. But when I use `\pgfmathresult` in the `yshift` value, it puts all copies of the picture in the same spot - essentially it acts as if `\pgfmathresult` evaluates to 0 regardless of what the actual result of the computation is. It's probably best illustrated by this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
      \pgfmathparse{2*\i}
      \begin{scope}[yshift=\pgfmathresult cm]
        \fill (0,0) circle(3pt);
      \end{scope}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The weird thing is that if I change `yshift` to `xshift`, the copies of the picture are spread out horizontally as I would expect. Is there some reason for this behavior, or is it a bug?

Comment: This is likely the same problem as, for example, here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9988/tikz-pgfmathresult-problem-inside-angle-pgfmathresult-coordinate or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10258/drawing-a-chord-net-with-tikz.

Comment: Side remark: you should be able to just write `[yshift=2*\i cm]`.

Comment: @Caramdir: okay, I didn't recognize either of those as the same problem. I thought the fact that it worked with `xshift` but not `yshift` suggested some deeper explanation.

Comment: And re: the side remark, the actual calculation is going to be something like `75*(\i - 1) pt`, which doesn't work when I put it directly in yshift.

Comment: @David: Yes you are right but It's preferable to never use `\pgfmathresult`directly. I think it's a good way to avoid this and in this case you have three solutions : you can avoid the use of a scope and the use of `pgfmathresult`, you can use shift and not yshift like Frédéric or you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro`

Comment: @David: with `75*(\i-1)pt` you can avoid the scope and use `\myshift`like in  my answer  `\draw[yshift=\myshift pt,fill] (0,0) circle(3pt);`

Comment: @Altermundus: yes, I did see your answer, thanks. I just wanted to point out that putting the mathematical expression itself directly as the value in `yshift=` is not a solution that works for me.

Comment: @David: try `yshift={(75*(\i - 1))*1pt}`

Comment: @Caramdir: ah, sneaky... thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better solution is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
        \draw[yshift=2*\i cm,fill] (0,0) circle(3pt);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but

It's always a good way to stock the `\pgfmathresult` in a personal macro or to use `\pgfmathsetmacro`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
      %\pgfmathparse{2*\i}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{2*\i} 
      \begin{scope}[yshift=\myshift cm]
        \fill (0,0) circle(3pt);
      \end{scope}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

now with `75*(\i - 1)`, Caramdir's remark is fine, we can use `75*(\i - 1)*1pt`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
        \draw[yshift=75*(\i - 1)* 1 pt,fill] (0,0) circle(3pt);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{2*\i}` in your second example?

Comment: @Caramdir: No you are right but I would like to keep the David's code. I updated my answer and you last remark is fine about `*1pt`

Answer (score 2):

I find that using `shift={(x,y)}]`is less prone to unwanted effects (I don't know why this is). In your case, you should write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
      \pgfmathparse{2*\i}
      \begin{scope}[shift={(0,\pgfmathresult)}]
        \fill (0,0) circle(3pt);
      \end{scope}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is then exactly what you are looking for :

[image]

Comment: The `shift={(x,y)}` is more "stable" because it reads the value as coordinate which is then parsed, but `xshift` and `yshift` await a simple *dimension*. In the first case you can use numbers without units.