# TikZ copy command

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does TikZ have a `copy` command? the copy command means, e.g.,

I draw a rectangle first, then I draw whatever e.g., circle, writing text etc. in the rectangle. let me define a `source object` that includes all objects in the rectangle and the rectangle itself. Now I want to `copy` the `source object` based on the lower left corner of rectangle to a new position.

@Martin @Jan @Caramdir, following is an example, but it has some error. please also refer to my comment.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{TikZ}   %Create PostScript and PDF graphics in TeX

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.962661,thick]
  \foreach \xbase/\ybase in {0mm/0mm,46.700000mm/0mm}
  {
    %grid line
    \draw[xstep=11.200000mm,ystep=12.051000mm] (\xbase,\ybase) grid (\xbase + 44.800000mm,\ybase + 36.153000mm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

@Martin @Jan @Caramdir, i updated the above example. it is better except that the most left vertical line of right grid is missing.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{TikZ}   %Create PostScript and PDF graphics in TeX

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.962661,thick]
  \foreach \xbase/\ybase/\xoffset in {0mm/0mm/0mm,44.800000mm/0mm/1.9mm}
  {
    %grid line
    \draw[xstep=11.200000mm,ystep=12.051000mm,xshift=\xoffset] (\xbase,\ybase) grid (\xbase + 44.800000mm,\ybase + 36.153000mm);
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

it seemed that `grid` always uses the origin (0,0) as its reference. my way is to add shift to the base point and cares about the coordinates by myself. but the most left vertical line of right grid is missing. i don't know why. it looked like that the line should be in the range of the grid.

is there a rationale for this? i mean make `grid` use (x,y) instead of (0,0) as the reference point.

Comment: Related question: ["How to rotate as copied in tikz"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9968/2975)

Comment: @Martin thank you for your direction. after reading the link, `foreach` loop seems a solution. define the base point and new position points in loop variable, then draw everything in loop body.

Comment: Just adding a comment many years on (in case someone stumbles across this question) that a feasible solution to this now would be to use the `pic` syntax to define repeatable "units" of TikZ code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other than using the `\foreach` command or defining a new command, you may repeat pictures by at least two other ways. (solution to the grid problem is found at the end of my answer)

1- (not tikz specific) : use the `\newsavebox`, `\savebox` and `\usebox` commands. The advantage of savebox is that the picture is not redrawn everytime it is called. For example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\test}
\savebox{\test}{\tikz \draw[red] (0,0) circle (1cm);}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node {\usebox{\test}};
\draw (7,0) node {\usebox{\test}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

2- (tikz specific) Use the object-oriented capabilities of tikz and pgf. The details are found in the tikz manual. For example, the code found on page 554 of the manual:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{oo}

\begin{document}

\pgfooclass{stamp}{ % This is the class stamp
    \method stamp() { % The constructor 
    }
    \method apply(#1,#2) { % Causes the stamp to be shown at coordinate (#1,#2)
        %Draw the stamp:
        \node [rotate=20] at (#1,#2) {Passed};
    }
}
\pgfoonew \mystamp=new stamp()
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \mystamp.apply(1,2)
        \mystamp.apply(3,4)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

About the grid problem. I don't have a good explanation about why the problem is occurring other than the shift in coordinates isn't being treated by tikz the way you expect them to (not much of an explanation I admit). A good way to solve the problem is to use the `scope` environment, and shift the whole environment, as described by the following code (I somewhat simplified your loop to make the `scope` environment stand out):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,thick]
  \foreach \xoffset in {0,5.2}
  {
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\xoffset,0)}]
        \draw[xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5);
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The `scope` environment acts as box that may be moved around (shifted or rotated) as a whole. If you are familiar with `pstricks`, it is similar to the `\rput` command.

Comment: your two method both worked. i prefer to the first method because i program with pure c (not at all c++). but, comparing with `\foreach` command or defining a new command, which one is better or more efficient? on the other hand, could you please have a look at the question about `grid ` in my original example?

Comment: @warem: I added a solution to your grid problem : use the scope environment.

Answer (score 14):

If I had to use the same contents several times in different places, I would define a new tex command that draws all the objects, and then use it at different locations, possibly with `scope` and shifting.  Something like this:

```
\newcommand\mytikzcontents{
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,5);
  \draw (1,1) circle (1cm);
  \draw[dashed,->] (4,5) -- (1,1);
}
```

and then inside the tikzpicture I would use it as

```
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=3cm]
   \mytikzcontents
\end{scope}
```

Or you could make the xshift and yshift arguments of the command.

Comment: i just start to learn tikz. now i don't know what `scope` means. i will refer it to `pgfmanual`. your method is similar to `foreach` loop i think. it is a good idea to define a new command to draw the source objects then use it wherever i want. thank you.

Comment: @warem: The scope basically passes its options to all the drawing commands inside the scope (plus it localizes clipping).

Comment: @Martin @Jan @Caramdir i added an example in the original text. it drew two girds which are exactly same. the left one's lower left corner is (0,0), the right one's is (46.7,0). there is a gap between the two girds. the gap is 1.9. but the right grid omit the gap. it is something about coordinate transformation. but the commad `grid` always counted on from (0,0).

Comment: @Martin @Jan @Caramdir i updated the example in the original text. please check it.

Comment: Is there a way to change your mytikzcontents any coordinate?