# Drawing randomly ragged lines in technical drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing, random-numbers

I am having issues getting started on drawing a randomly ragged line, with finite variation, between two endpoints.
The `random` function which uses variable `rnd` I think can be used, for instance, [Drawing random paths in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11680/drawing-random-paths-in-tikz), but I have no idea how to use it for this purpose.

I use this environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % SIZE OF FONT AND ITS LAYOUT ON EACH PAGE.
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry} % MARGINS.
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, graphicx, setspace}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph,tikz-cd} % DIAGRAMS.
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8,auto]

% replace with randomly ragged line \draw [-,line width=1pt] (0,2) edge (2,2);
\draw [-,line width=1pt,dashed] (0,0) edge (0,2);% solid left boundary
\draw [-,line width=1pt,white] (0,0) edge (8,0);% solid lower boundary
\draw [-,line width=1pt,dashed] (8,0) edge (8,2);% solid right boundary
% make a vertical rule fill; how? How would I make a tiled rule fill, in case that looks better?

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    \caption{CAPTION GOES HERE}
        \label{fig:FIGURE NAME GOES HERE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would like to re-create this:

[image]

EDIT: I think Jesse's example most produces the required result, but it cannot remove fill line segments that cross it, unlike the other two solutions.

**How do I copy a generated random line after it is generated and change its color so that I have two parallel random lines?** (Then the user can place one slightly above the other, but white and thick, but below it in code. This will crop all fill lines going beyond it manually.) I am trying [TikZ copy command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12106/tikz-copy-command) but this shifts the entire picture right and creates the copy of the random line beside it.

Comment: The first error that I see, is that the command `\begin{document}` is missed.

Comment: ... fixed; forgot it when I pasted this out of the document.

Comment: Related: [Simulating hand-drawn lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another alternative, inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126179/34618

[image: Resulting Image when running the code below]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\irregularline[2]{%
  let \n1 = {rand*(#1)} in
  +(0,\n1)
  \foreach \a in {0.1,0.2,...,#2}{
    let \n1 = {rand*(#1)} in
    -- +(\a,\n1)
  } 
}  % #1=seed, #2=length of horizontal line


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue] (0,0) \irregularline{0.1cm}{6} -- (6,0)--(6,-2) --(0,-2) -- (0,0);
\foreach \t in {0,0.1,...,6} {\draw (\t,0) -- (\t,-2);}

\draw[red]  (0,2) \irregularline{2mm}{6};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE: for vertical drawing. One simply switches the coordinates in the command line as displayed below and an example.

```
\newcommand\irregularliney[2]{%
  let \n1 = {rand*(#1)} in
  +(\n1,0)
  \foreach \a in {0.1,0.2,...,#2}{
    let \n1 = {rand*(#1)} in
    -- +(\n1,\a)
  } 
}  % #1=seed, #2=length

\draw[yellow,thick] (0,0) \irregularliney{0.1cm}{6} -- (0,6)--(-2,6) --(-2,0) -- (0,0);
```

Comment: Can I make a similar command that connects two arbitrary points? Or at least, how do I make a similar command that is vertical? Can the line be made thicker? Also, how can I clip the fill? If I can copy the line once it is generated and turn it white and thick I could clip the fill manually by making a white thick line identical to the ragged line and shifting it up a few points.

Comment: The easiest way is to switch the coordinates in (0,\n1) and (\a,\n1) in the command definition for vertical line.

Comment: @GuidoJorg -- Please see my update.

Comment: @GuidoJorg -- for line thickness. Use the option [line width=xxpt] or ultra thin, very thin, thin,..., semithick, thick, very thick, ultra thick. As to clipping, sorry, don't quite follow you.

Comment: Regarding clipping I mean, that the part of the vertical lines are made invisible if they reach above the random line: see the example below or above. How do I copy a generated random line and change its color so that I have two parallel random lines, one slightly above the other, but white and thick?

Comment: @GuidoJorg -- Not sure if this is what you want, thus did not update my OP. I'll simply give a shot. Check this please.  \begin{scope}
\clip (0,2) rectangle(6,2.3);
\draw  (0,2) \irregularline{2mm}{6};
\end{scope}
\foreach \t in {0,0.1,...,6} {\draw[red](\t,2) -- (\t,0);}

Comment: Not quite. This clips the top of the line if I do that and replace and it clips the bottom of the random line. I am trying to reproduce Marienplatz's example with tikz, because I am combining this with some complicated mapping tikz diagrams. I would like to use your random line for this because it looks best and is easiest to edit the result. Should I accept your answer and start a new topic regarding getting the clipping to work?

Comment: Ya, maybe a new topic would help.

Answer (score 8):

You can obtain similar result using the tikz library `decorations.pathmorphing`, that allows you to create decorations with `radom steps`. Also, using the `clip` option in `path` you can cut the vertical lines at the upper line of random form, but this should draw all boundary region of the clipping path, hence a horizontal line at bottom has been drawn, also vertical lines has been drawn at right and left but this goes with the drawing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}[gray,thick]
                \draw (-0.1,-0.5) -- (-0.1,-1) (-0.1,-1.5) -- (-0.1,-2) (-0.1,-2.5) -- (-0.1,-3);
                \draw (10.1,-0.5) -- (10.1,-1) (10.1,-1.5) -- (10.1,-2) (10.1,-2.5) -- (10.1,-3);
            \end{scope}
            \path[draw,clip,decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=2pt}] decorate {(0,0) -- (10,0)} |- (0,-3.5);
            \foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,10} {
                \draw (\x,1) -- (\x,-3.5);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Are there any more parameters that can control the shape of the random line? This works well but I am trying to go for a more sawtooth result?

Comment: No, there are no additional parameters. The decoration should be random? You can use `decoration={saw,segment length=3pt,amplitude=2pt}` for a beautiful sawtooth.

Comment: What about quasi-random, in sense that more spikes but they don't intersect? My idea is to compress the entire line once drawn by a multiple, but keep segment length and amplitude 2.7 and 2.3; can this be done? Also, how do I make the line thicker?

Comment: To change the thickness in a clipping path you need use a `preaction`, so the command is: `\path[clip,preaction={draw,very thick},decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=2pt}]`. Maybe you're interested in this question: [Custom decoration along curved paths](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134259/custom-decoration-along-curved-paths).

Answer (score 6):

A recommended solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}
\psset{linejoin=1}
\def\N{30}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,5)
    \psline(6,0)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\N]{0}{6}{t 5 Rand 2 mul sub}{A}
    \psnline[linecolor=red](0,\Anodecount){A}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\N}{\psline(A\i|0,0)(A\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animated

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}
\psset{linejoin=1}
\def\N{30}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}(6,3)
    \psline(6,0)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\N]{0}{6}{t 3 Rand 2 mul sub}{A}
    \psnline[linecolor=red](0,\Anodecount){A}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\N}{\psline(A\i|0,0)(A\i)}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Attention

Note that `Rand` no longer produces a random real number between 0 and 0.5 inclusive. Its definition had been tacitly changed. Now it produces a random real number between 0 and 1 inclusive. It is not documented, nor announced, but it is still fun!

The code given above has not been updated yet so it will produce different output. I have no time to update it right now. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: Is there anyway to do exactly this in tikz? Or combine this with tikz to make a complicated graphic?

Comment: @GuidoJorg: PSTricks without TikZ can make more complicated than this one. Merging PSTricks and TikZ in the same canvas might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I know is almost one year ago question, but I want share my solution. This is the code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\NewDocumentCommand{\irregularline}{%
  O     {2mm}   % Amplitude of irregularity. Optional. Default value = 2mm
  m             % First point
  m             % Second point
  D   <> {20}   % Number of peaks. Optional. Default value = 20
}{{%
  \coordinate (old) at #2;
  \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#4}{
    \draw (old) -- ($ ($#2!\i/(#4+1)!#3$) + (0,#1*rand) $) coordinate (old);
  }
  \draw (old) -- #3;
}}

% Examples
\irregularline{(0,0)}{(5,5)}
\irregularline[1mm]{(1,0)}{(6,5)}
\irregularline[1mm]{(2,0)}{(7,5)}<100>

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That produce the follow output:

[image]