# Scribbled out crossed out text

Tags: packages

How would one be able to reproduce the scribbling of text in LaTeX?

Something like this superimposed on text:

[image]

**Ideally:**

latex code:

```
% using the four scribble patterns (top to bottom)

\bigscribble{Can} \mediumscribble{this} \smallscribble{be} \flatscribble{done}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Probably, but it might be a little complex. Especially if you want the line to follow the length of the text you enter into the commands. Perhaps this post might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143070/drawing-randomly-ragged-lines-in-technical-drawings, as well as this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines.